# Update ms access database via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, database-connection

How can I do that?

I already have the code I'm working on but it seems that it doesnt work really fine.
Here is how my program works. I input an id number(unique) on a text box and click the search button. The entries that corresponds to the id number is then displayed on the other text boxes.

And then I try to edit one of the entries manually(changing its letters or name) then I click the update button.

Here is now the problem: It really updates the entry but it makes a mirror of the entry with a different id number(maybe automatically generated).
So basically the ms access database will now contain the old entry and the updated version of the entry.

I can show you my code if you wish to. As long as I am assured by your reputation in this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show the code, seems like you are using **insert** instead of **update**.

OK, check this link [DataAdapter.Update Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx)

You seem to be missing

```
' Without the OleDbCommandBuilder this line would fail.
builder.GetUpdateCommand()
```

before

```
adapter.Update(dataSet)
```

Let me know if this works?